# Removing names from noun chunks in spacy

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Is there a way to remove name of person in noun chunks ?

Here is the code

```
import en_vectors_web_lg
nlp = en_vectors_web_lg.load()
text = "John Smith is lookin for Apple ipod"
doc = nlp(text)
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
     print(chunk.text)
```

Current output

```
John Smith
Apple ipod
```

I would like to have an output like below where name of the people is ignored. How to achieve this ?

```
Apple ipod
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference [spaCy ents](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#101)

```
import spacy
# loading the model
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
doc = nlp(u'"John Smith is lookin for Apple ipod"')
# creating the filter list for tokens that are identified as person
fil = [i for i in doc.ents if i.label_.lower() in ["person"]]
# looping through noun chunks
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    # filtering the name of the person
    if chunk not in fil:
        print(chunk.text)
```

Output:

```
Apple ipod
```

Hope this helps.